# windows azure table storage, how do I enable keep alive

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Currently I put to azure table storage like this:

```
public static void AzurePut(string Key, byte[] Value)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

    var keyhash = MyTable.CalculateMD5Hash(Key);
    var tc = MyTable.GetBinFromHash(keyhash, AzureTables.TableCount);
    CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("table" + tc);

    var entity = new AzureEntity();
    entity.Key = keyhash;
    entity.SetValue(Value);

    TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);
    table.Execute(insertOperation);
}
```

I do a lot of puts and they are slow. When I open fidller they become like 40 times faster. After checking why it turns out that fiddler reuses connections with connection: keep-alive headers. Is there any way to do this using table storage api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short**:
Add this to the start-up code of your application:

```
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100; // Default 2
        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false; // Default true
```

**Explanation**

You don't have to add any Keep-Alive headers, they are already there. Have a look at [`HttpWebRequestFactory`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Shared/Protocol/HttpWebRequestFactory.cs) (line 86):

```
#if WINDOWS_DESKTOP && !WINDOWS_PHONE
            request.KeepAlive = true;

            // Disable the Expect 100-Continue
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
#endif

            return request;
        }
```

On top of that [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.protocolversion(v=vs.110).aspx) uses HTTP 1.1 by default which [makes connection persistent by default](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1.2)

You can use [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to see that connection is being reused.

Fiddler is so fast mostly because it's extremely clever about reusing connections, batching and buffering requests, especially when your application is making a lot of parallel requests.

By default `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` is 2 which means that you can have only 2 pending requests at the same time. Imagine you have 8 threads trying to make a request, 2 of them can be active at time, the rest is waiting. Raising the limit greatly improves  concurrent requests.

Another issue is that `ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm` is enabled by default. Since most of Azure Table requests are relatively small(HTTP message size < 1460 bytes), they are unnecessary buffered. See much longer explanation of this [at Microsoft Azure Storage Team Blog (Nagle’s Algorithm is Not Friendly towards Small Requests)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/06/25/nagle-s-algorithm-is-not-friendly-towards-small-requests.aspx)